# Which webGL/Canvas library should be used for 2D animation with clipping/masking of images using custom shapes

Tags: library, javascript, svg

**I want to use Canvas/WebGL technologies for creating lots of full Width/Height background images with custom shapes clipping/masking.**

Here are the features I am looking for:

- Layers
- Custom shapes
- Clipping/Masking
- Images
- 2d drawing - 3d is not important
- Should be easy to animate (I will use Greensock for animation).

I have found some famous libraries for canvas like:

- **[Three.js](http://threejs.org/)**
- **[pixi.js](http://www.pixijs.com/)**
- **[Kinetic.js](http://kineticjs.com/)**
- **[Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/)**
- etc...

**Example Of Usage:** A fixed canvas behind the website content, with cover image(full width & height) masked in to two sections which animated and reveal the cover image as the users scroll.

**What i have tried:** I have used kinetic.js but it is very poor with clipping/masking features -- In starting, it looked like the right choice for 2D controls but I feel like all my time have been wasted on this as it has a very poor support for using custom shapes for clipping over images.

**My Particular Scenario:** I am making a parallax site using **[ScrollMagic](http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/)** & **[Greensock](http://www.greensock.com/)** plugin. I have 7 ~ 8 sections each with its own background image which animates in a fancy way using svg -- but svg is very low performance and i want to switch it with a canvas -- I have done that already using kinetic.js, but it does not provide any good support for clipping custom shapes on images for animation.

**Any suggestion would be much appreciated.**

Answer (score 1):

CreateJS would be a comprehensive choice. It offers the following tools:

- [TweenJS](https://www.createjs.com/demos/tweenjs/simpletweendemo)
- [EaselJS | A JavaScript library that makes working with the HTML5 Canvas element easy.](https://www.createjs.com/easeljs)
- [PreloadJS | A JavaScript library that lets you manage and co-ordinate the loading of assets.](https://www.createjs.com/preloadjs)